# In a django template, how to access dynamically to each attribute for every database table row?

Tags: python, django, templates, attributes

I'm building a table in a django template to show all the records from a database table.
I need to build dynamically (both rows and columns) but I am having problems to access each record attribute. My code's result, is an empty table with the same amount of database rows.

I created a variable `field_name` to be assigned the attribute name, and then access that attribute aplying this variable to each record. The result, is an empty table with the same amount of database rows.

I printed `field_name` and the attribute name is assigned okey, but then it's not applied correctly to the record.

How should I code it?

```
<tbody>
   {% for record in table_records %}
      <tr>
        {% for field in table_fields %}
           {% with field_name = field.name %}
              <td>{{ record.field_name }}</td>
           {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: directly not possible ... maybe a custom template filter helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724569/dynamically-display-field-values-in-django-template-object-x

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73454706/adding-rows-and-columns-to-html-table-with-django/73454813#73454813